# From where can I get "Python Launcher" for Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-lion, python, pip

I use a macbook (air) with OS X Lion on it. I have Python 2.7 installed already but I can't seem to find a "Python Launcher.app" anywhere on the system.

I tried installing with with *pip* but it couldn't find anything to fetch.

I tried searching on Google to find a downloader but my search yielded no results (for downloading).

Where can I get this app? I have a folder with 20+ subfolders of GUI examples which in turn contain anywhere from 3 to 5 subfolders. I don't want to go through each within the terminal, would much rather launch these .py scrips from the finder.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Odd. I have a Python Launcher. Not sure how I got it though.

Comment: Hello @AceLegend. Since I could not find a download link through search, I assume that what's odd is me not having it. ;-) Your's seems to be the normal case.

Comment: Yeah. Oh. I got my Python tools when I was setting up either the Firefox Development tools, Chrome, or Webkit? I believe I used brew, where did you download yours? Brew, Online, another tool (I forgot what that other command-line download tool was called.

Comment: Hi @AceLegend! I had not downloadd Python, hence the apparent reason of my lack of that Python utility. ;-) After some research and questioning on the internet, I was told that a download was necessary and it's indeed advisable to download Python separately for development purposes rather than relying on Apple-supplied Python executables. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to install Python from the python.org website to get it.